# MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently testing out MongoDB(4.4) Drivers with nodeJS(no mongoose) and trying to connect to localhost:27107. The code below is pretty much copy/paste from the official documentation test code. MongoDB is nicely running in the back.
However, on my command line I get error messages seen as below. Could anyone help me with solving this?

error message:

> MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/miya/Desktop/FruitsProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {   reason: TopologyDescription {
> type: 'Single',
> setName: null,
> maxSetVersion: null,
> maxElectionId: null,
> servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27107' => [ServerDescription] },
> stale: false,
> compatible: true,
> compatibilityError: null,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
> heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
> localThresholdMS: 15,
> commonWireVersion: null   } }

My code in app.js looks like this;

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Connection URI
const uri =
  "mongodb://localhost:27107";

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server
    await client.connect();

    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

const dbName = "fruitDB";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your mongoDB server running ?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I have the community server running in the back I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this thing happens most of the time may be there is Ip restriction issues or anyother to resolve this issue there are two ways

1. use mongoose instead of mongodb lib
   here is the code for connection

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
  mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

2)if you are using atlas then  use the connection string for 2 or lower nodejs version

Comment: Mongoose isn't necessarily "better" here

Comment: Mongoose is a ORM for mongoDb

Comment: I know. The question wasn't asking about it, however. Read the question again, says "no mongoose"

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Firewall application, you can open the Start menu and type “firewall” into the search bar. Then click on the “Windows Firewall” option and then on the “Advanced Settings” option. Then click on “Inbound Rules” and then on “New Rule”. Select “Port” as the rule type and click “Next”. Enter “27017” as the port number and click “Next”. Select “Allow the connection” as the action and click “Next”. Choose which network types to apply the rule to and click “Next”. Give a name and a description for the rule and click “Finish” 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).